# Digital Mars - unable to open input file 'iostream'

Tags: c++, iostream, stlport

I'm using "Digital Mars" to compile the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   cout <<"My name is Abder-Rahman";
   return 0;
}
```

And, this is what I get:

C:\Users\Software Engineer\Desktop\C++\dm852c\dm\bin>dmc print1
Fatal error: unable to open input file 'iostream'
--- errorlevel 1

Any ideas on that?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your source being compiled AS C++?

Comment: definitely check out this [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review"). It's almost there, just needs a little more support.

Comment: @greatwolf: What do you mean?

Comment: @phresnel That comment's 3+ years old for raising awareness to codereview. But I'm not sure why you're asking about it now since it's long past it's launching phase.

Comment: @greatwolf: Ah oh whoops, sorry :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check *VernonDozier* answer about [this problem](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread340777.html):

> The code is fine. Your compiler installation is probably broken. You have a bad include path, permissions problems, or you have files missing.

Your compiler is probably misconfigured. I recommend you to read [this post](http://code-blue.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=16%3aworking-with-dmc&catid=10%3aarticles&Itemid=12).

Comment: Digital Mars comes as a zipped folder, I unzipped the folder once again and now it works. Thanks.

Comment: @SWEngineer Great. Don't forget to mark this answer as accepted. Actually, you haven't officially accepted any answers so far. Review your other questions and start accepting some, else people will stop to help you in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Modify file sc.ini in c:\dm\bin  as follows then save it

```
[Version]
version=857

[Environment]
PATH=%PATH%;"%@P%\..\bin"
BIN="%@P%\..\bin"
INCLUDE="%@P%\..\stlport\stlport";"%@P%\..\include";"%@P%\..\mfc\include";%INCLUDE%
;INCLUDE="%@P%\..\include";"%@P%\..\mfc\include";%INCLUDE%
LIB="%@P%\..\lib";"%@P%\..\mfc\lib";%LIB%
HELP="%@P%\..\help"
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that is is **too late** for an answer but in case someone (like me) likes using Digital Mars and lands here, you can use `sc filename.cpp -Ic:\path\where\stlport`, where the I is capital, there is **no** space between the `-I` and the path where  [STLport 4.5.3](https://digitalmars.com/download/freecompiler.html)  was extracted.